# Angular 8 + Firebase: Cannot initialize project due to AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)

Tags: angular, firebase, angular8

I am having trouble in connecting Angular + Firebase due to this one line of code.

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
```

The error is: ***Property 'firebase' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.ts(2339)***
app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule, AngularFirestore } from 
'@angular/fire/firestore';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from "./signup/signup.component"

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If you need any more segments of code from my project please let me know. Any help or feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `/src/environments/environment.ts` file with your Firebase configuration: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md#3-add-firebase-config-to-environments-variable

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this issue by copy and pasting the content of `environment.ts` to `environment.prod.ts`, like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "project.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "project",
    storageBucket: "project.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using environment.prod.ts worked!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35463706)